# Using Cypress how to obtain session Id

Tags: session, cypress

I was using Cypress to obtain a session ID which i could use to trigger the API. Tried all possible known combination, but i am not able to get one. Please see the code i had used

```
    cy.session("Authorisation Token",()=>{
        
        cy.visit('application URL');
        cy.wait(2000);
       
        cy.window().then((win) => {
        const someItem = win.sessionStorage.getItem('msal.idtoken');// The header name is specified for which i am trying to obtain the value. This value need to be consumed
        cy.log(someItem);
        })
```

On running the above code i get a null value. Kindly advise.

Comment: I'd say check first if `msal` exists.

Comment: If you `console.log()` the `someItem` variable, do you get a value in the console? This might be an issue with `cy.log()` being called before `someItem` has a value.

Answer (score 0):

There are different recipes for logging in in the [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/examples/examples/recipes#Logging-In).

For me, getting the JSESSIONID value from the cookie worked like this:

```
cy.contains("Aktuelle Bestellungen")
        .should("be.visible")
        .then(() => {
            cy.getCookie("JSESSIONID").then((cookie) =>
                cy.log(cookie.value)
            );
        });
```